# Delete/remove a calendar in Android AccountManager's database using Tasker intent?

Tags: calendar, tasker, java, intents

While trying to remove calendars from the Android AccountManager's database using Tasker, I've been exploring the [Android calendar provider api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) but I have not been able to find a command to delete a calendar once it is identified.

Based on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#calendar, I tried to use the tasker intent commands to first create a calendar with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setData(CalendarContract.Calendars._ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I have found an event deleting command here:
    https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#delete-event. It think it deletes eventId 201.

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MyActivity";
...
long eventID = 201;
...
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri deleteUri = null;
deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
int rows = cr.delete(deleteUri, null, null);
Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Rows deleted: " + rows);
```

My **question** is: *does anyone have a suggestion on a java command/intent that can be used to delete a calendar account once I found one?*

---

**Edit:**

I was looking for the [accountmanager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager). After finding the correct String value for parameter "Type" I can get a list of calendars using the [`getAccountsByType()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#getAccountsByType(java.lang.String)). Afterwards I should be able to loop through that list and apply either the `[removeAccount(Account account, Activity activity, AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback, Handler handler)][4]`, or the [`removeAccountExplicitly(Account account)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#removeAccountExplicitly(android.accounts.Account)) method.

[This is an example script](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tasker/Z6nioMVgC6E/mupTP4HvoIcJ) that retrieves the list of android Accounts. Part A1-A11 has been tested and verified with export constraints:

- Package name consists of `<1 letter>.<1 letter>.com`
- In advanced app export settings in tasker set the additional permission to:`android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS`.

This is the tested tasker `.xml` file of the example script, which I am currently working on:

```
    <TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="5.2.bf1">
    <Task sr="task27">
        <cdate>1545421710313</cdate>
        <edate>1545513273938</edate>
        <id>27</id>
        <nme>removeDavAccountsAD</nme>
        <pri>100</pri>
        <Kid sr="Kid">
            <eperm0>android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS</eperm0>
            <eperm1>android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS</eperm1>
            <eperm2>android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS</eperm2>
            <eperm3>android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS</eperm3>
            <eperm4>android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER</eperm4>
            <flgs>1</flgs>
            <launchID>27</launchID>
            <pkg>a.be.com</pkg>
            <vMin>25</vMin>
            <vTarg>25</vTarg>
            <vnme>1.0</vnme>
            <vnum>27</vnum>
        </Kid>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">am</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">AccountManager</Str>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">get
{AccountManager} (Context)</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3">CONTEXT</Str>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">accounts</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">am</Str>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">getAccounts
{Account[]} ()</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act10" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">am</Str>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">removeAccountExplicitly
{boolean} (Account)</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3">accounts[%item]</Str>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%a_type</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>*at.bitfire.davdroid*</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act11" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">After: %a_name</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%a_type</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>*at.bitfire.davdroid*</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act12" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">am</Str>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">removeAccount
{AccountManagerFuture} (Account, Activity, AccountManagerCallback, android.os.Handler)</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3">accounts[%item]</Str>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%a_type</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>*at.bitfire.davdroid*</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act13" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">am</Str>
<Str sr="arg2" ve="3">removeAccount
{AccountManagerFuture} (Account, AccountManagerCallback, android.os.Handler)</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3">accounts[%item]</Str>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%a_type</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>*at.bitfire.davdroid*</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act14" ve="7">
            <code>40</code>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act15" ve="7">
            <code>665</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">am</Str>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%accounts_length</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">accounts.length</Str>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">assign
{int} ()</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act3" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Number of accounts: %accounts_length</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act4" ve="7">
            <code>890</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%accounts_length</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act5" ve="7">
            <code>39</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%item</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">0:%accounts_length</Str>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act6" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <se>false</se>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%a_name</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">accounts[%item].name</Str>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">toString
{String} ()</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act7" ve="7">
            <code>664</code>
            <se>false</se>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%a_type</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">accounts[%item].type</Str>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">toString
{String} ()</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg9" ve="3"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act8" ve="7">
            <code>410</code>
            <se>false</se>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">/storage/17EE-2356/titwatest/AccountManager_Accounts1.txt</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%a_name;%a_type</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="1"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%a_type</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>*bitfire.at.davdroid*/*at.bitfire.davdroid*</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act9" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%a_name</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%a_type</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>*at.bitfire.davdroid*</rhs>
                </Condition>
</ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Img sr="icn" ve="2">
            <nme>hl_collections_go_to_today</nme>
        </Img>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

As soon as I have been able to modify/expand it to delete the accounts, I shall post the solution here as answer.